# Are there any Latin words with sharply contrasting meanings?

Tags: vocabulary, meaning, semantics

The English word *madam* can mean

> - A polite form of address for a woman or lady.
> - (slang) A woman who runs a brothel, particularly one that specializes in finding prostitutes for rich and important clients.

([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/madam))

These two meanings stand in great contrast. One is a civilized form of address, and the other connotes an uncivilized activity (i.e. prostitution).

Are there any Latin words with sharply contrasting meanings, like the contrast we see above?

Comment: Written down, *nitens* means either, 'slaving away,' 0r 'sparkling.' One has a short **i**, the other long. But, closer to your choice though not as dramatic, Q. mentions *Gallus* "whether it means a cock or a Gaul or a proper name or an emasculated priest of tybele; " Perseus tufts has this on-line: http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/ (Quintilian Inst. Bk7 ch9.5+)

Comment: *Dominus* was similar to "madam" in that it could either be very respectful or very insulting depending how it was used. *Rex* even more so. (Imagine addressing the President as "your majesty" in a heavily sarcastic way.)

Comment: Concerning the example, I think it's misleading to think of these as two contrasting meanings. It seems more like the second is just an ironic riff off the first. "My dear sir" is quite frequently used derisively, but it would be a stretch to call it a different meaning.

Answer (score 6):

My suggestion is ***testis***, which means both "testicle" and "witness".
The two meanings of "madam" seem related; both refer to "a female with a significant status" or something like that.
The two meanings of *testis* seem unrelated.

The potential for humor did not go unnoticed in antiquity.
In *Curculio* Plautus writes *quod amas amato testibus praesentibus*.
To love in the presence of witnesses seems to mean getting formally married or something similar.
I will let you figure out the other meaning…

Answer (score 2):

The *malum* can mean bad and *malus* an evildoer, or it can mean a mast/pole, or an apple tree.

The word *furo* can mean to steal or to be furious.

The noun *populo* means by the people, but the verb *populo* means to devastate.

The verb *scindo* means to tear, but it can also mean to commit pederasty.

The verbs *molo* (grind) and *depso* (knead) and *aro* (plow) all have predictable sexual meanings.

Comment: You might want to mention vowel quantities: _malus_ and _mālus_ were as distinct as _anus_ and _annus_ (i.e. similar but not identical).

Answer (score 1):

Discussing Q: [To be Overcharged, Short-Changed & Swindled](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/18785/1982), in CHAT, recently, looking for ways of expressing "to be shortchanged" cmw suggested verb, "emungo" = "to trick"; "to swindle"; but, also, "to wipe one's nose" (Oxford).